# Is it possible to use conditional formatting and group by together in a Power BI measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I've been trying to find a suitable answer to my problem but couldn't do it.

I have a large dataset that looks similar to this sample. In this image you can see different employees that have a duplicate expense amount in different reports or in the same report. In the case of the first employee, he has two duplicates for the same amount, one on each report. The Spanish employee and the Mexican one have the same duplicate amount twice on the same report.
[image]

I would like to be able to highlight the records that meet this condition: whether the duplicate amount is in one report or in two different reports:

[image]

Is it possible? Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Are your snips cropped off? Can only see one entry of the Emp 2 and for Emp4. Is Red = same amount different report, Orange = same amount same report? And assuming they have to be same date as well? And is the above all in one data table?

Comment: Hi @SamNseir, thank your time. No, my snips are not cropped off. When the same amount appears on the same report I want it to be in just one single row. Yes, red when the same amount appears in two differents reports and orange when it appears on the same report. The date is not important. In the same day, you can make two or three differents reports. And yes, all this info is in one data table.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The orange ones, are they one or two rows in the data table? Are the snips from a visual, data table, or a mock-up? Are you able to achieve the first snip as a table visual in Power BI?

Comment: The orange ones are two rows in the data table, but the snips are a sample of the table visual, because they have the same report_id just one row is shown. Sorry if it wasn't clear. @SamNseir

Comment: Measure or Calculated Column?

Comment: Measure, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a measure like:

```
DuplicateType = 
  var emp = SELECTEDVALUE(Expenses[employee])
  var amt = SELECTEDVALUE(Expenses[amount])
  var rid = SELECTEDVALUE(Expenses[report_id])

  var countDifferentReports = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Expenses), ALLSELECTED(Expenses), Expenses[employee] = emp && Expenses[amount] = amt && Expenses[report_id] <> rid)
  var countSameReports = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Expenses), ALLSELECTED(Expenses), Expenses[employee] = emp && Expenses[amount] = amt && Expenses[report_id] = rid)

  return SWITCH(TRUE(),
    countDifferentReports > 0 && countSameReports > 1, "D+S",
    countDifferentReports > 0, "D",
    countSameReports > 1, "S"
  )
```

Then for your conditional formatting have something like:
[image]

```
D   = Different Report  
S   = Same Report  
D+S = Different and Same Report (edge case maybe)
```

Comment: It works!! Again, thank you so much for your time :)